# Two columns liquid layout with header and footer

Tags: html, css, css-position, fluid-layout

My HTML page with 2 columns and footer and header:

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="header"> </div>
   <div class="left"> </div>
   <div class="data"> </div>
   <div class="bottom"> </div>
</div>
```

In my case I want left DIV with auto width and data DIV with 100% width. Like on this image:
[image]
How to CSS with IE 6 support? Thank you!

Comment: can you post the css you have so far

Comment: Avoid IE6 support :) It's better for You, your project, your client and web community. Really

Comment: Something http://jsfiddle.net/z8hbgena/1/ but DIVs have another names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/s37z0pfu/1/)**

html

```
<div class="header">
    header content
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    footer content
</div>
```

css

```
body, html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    height:100%
}
.header, .footer{
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.content{
    background:#eee;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
}
.left{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    background:#bbb;
    height:100%;
}
.right{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    background:#aaa;
    height:100%;
}
```

---

as required **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/s37z0pfu/6/)**

css

keeping everything same as above just change below css

```
.content{
    background:#eee;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
    display:table
}
.left{
    width:auto;
    background:#bbb;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell
}
.right{
    background:#aaa;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: Can I set left DIV width auto and right DIV width 100% ?

Comment: yes.. some edits in code will do it, but then I am not sure of ie6 compatibility. or else you can give width like 30% to left and 70% to right.. or something like that if it fulfils your purpose.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s37z0pfu/5/ - not worked for left DIV width auto and right DIV width 100%

Comment: not that way.. you need to change the code a bit.. let me do that for u.. wait for some minutes.. busy with something else..

Comment: you need to put some content in left div, as it has width:auto;. so if no content is present it will take 0 width. checkout this http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/s37z0pfu/8/

Comment: I put some text to left DIV http://jsfiddle.net/s37z0pfu/10/ but not see Pikday calendar

Answer (score 0):

It will work i think.
Please check and let me know.

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.mainbody,
.header,
.footer {
    padding: 5px;
}
.mainbody {
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 388px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.header {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.footer {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.left{
width:50%;
float:left;
background:#bbb;
height:100%;
}
.right{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    background:#aaa;
    height:100%;
}

<div id="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="mainbody">
        <div class="left">left</div>
        <div class="right">right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```